# deploying django website on apache server

Tags: python, django, apache, web-deployment

I am new to Django and has no experience deploying website other that to htdocs folder. I want to deploy Django website to apache server seen a lot of tutorial but could not understood what to do.
my configuration is :

```
Apache version: Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30
server root:    c:/xammp/apache
python version: 3.6.0
Django version: 1.10.6
```

I downloaded mod-python 3.5.0.gz after extracting and paste it in apache/modules folder then I try editing mod-python in httpd.conf by adding

```
LoadModule python_module modules/mod_python.so
```

but it failed to start so I removed itfrom httpd.conf and now apachestarts fine

Comment: If you don't understand the tutorial, how will you understand any answer we give? Please show exactly what you did, and what you didn't understand.

Comment: edited my question may be I am doing something wrong in step .one thing I observed was file extension of mod-python it was .o but rest all file in modules folder were .os by default

Comment: There can't be any Django tutorial or documentation written in the last eight years that mentions mod-python. Why are you using that? Please read [the official docs for deploying with modwsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) and follow the link to the [modwsgi installation docs](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installation.html).

Comment: Thank yoy i was using old tutorial now when i use command pip install wsgi error comes saying vc14 required install with building tool

Answer (score 0):

Here's an automated Django deployment script I just wrote. Hope it helps you out. https://github.com/dancaron/djangogo